# How to set datePicker Date Range with maxDate 1 month?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How could I set a max days gap between two date pickers? I have two date pickers
`from` date picker with id `from` and `to` date picker with id  `to`.

Required behavior:

1. if I select `from` date `2019-12-17` then the max date of `to` date picker must be today `2019-12-23`.
2. if I select `from` date `2019-01-01` then max date of `to` date picker must be `2019-01-31`

I have the code which I mentioned below.

```
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd",
    from = $("#from")
    .datepicker({
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "-100:+0",
      maxDate: 0,
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      altField: "#fromInput",
      dateFormat: dateFormat
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));

    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "-100:+0",
      maxDate: 0,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      altField: "#toInput",
      dateFormat: dateFormat
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }
});
```

In above code the 1st expected behavior is working but not the second one.

Comment: strange requirement. in your first scenario you just added 5 days,
and in the second you added a month for to date.

Comment: Please correct me in your title you said that you wanted to add a month range in `to` date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To set date range of one month from current date, we will use 'M'
>   option to "+1" for maxDate and for minDate "0" So the current date
>   becomes the value of minDate. See below jQuery code.

```
<div id="datepicker">


$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+1M'
    });
});
```